# xquery to convert attributes to tags

Tags: xml, xquery

I am learning on Xquery. I have this tag in my XML document.

```
<element a="1" b="2" c="3" name="testgroupID">198</element>
<element a="11" b="12" c="13" name="testgroupverifyID" binary="hidden"/>
```

May I know how to create something like the following with xquery?

```
<mytags>
    <a>1</a>
    <b>2</b>
    <c>3</c>
    <name>testgroupID</name>
    <value>198</value>
</mytags>
<mytags>
    <a>11</a>
    <b>12</b>
    <c>13</c>
    <name>testgroupverifyID</name>
    <binary>hidden</binary>
</mytags>
```

Currently I could only use the static way to do it, like:

$tag := $x/@a
and then return it with {$tag

Kindly advise. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XQuery:

```
for $elem in /root/element
return element mytags {
          for $child in $elem/(@*|text())
          return element {if ($child instance of attribute())
                          then name($child)
                          else 'value'} {
                    string($child)
                 }
       }
```

Output:

```
<mytags>
    <a>1</a>
    <b>2</b>
    <c>3</c>
    <name>testgroupID</name>
    <value>198</value>
</mytags>
<mytags>
    <a>11</a>
    <b>12</b>
    <c>13</c>
    <name>testgroupverifyID</name>
    <binary>hidden</binary>
</mytags>
```